# After upgrading to Python 3.11.4 _ctypes not found

Tags: python, python-3.x

After upgrading to python 3.11.4 received the following error in running a script:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'

I discovered I needed python3.11-distutils.
While researching I tried to run the following:

```
sudo apt install python3.11-distutils 
package could be found
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.11-distutils
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.11-distutils'
```

How can I install this package?

Comment: I don't think you need python3.11-distutils. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: How did you do the upgrade?  `ctypes` is built-in to Python.  `_ctypes` (which is its helper DLL) should always be available, if you've installed it normally.

Comment: I followed the steps in this article: How to Install Python 3.11.4 on the Raspberry Pi at url: https://aruljohn.com/blog/python-raspberrypi/